# On Canadian Employment Insurance (EI) do you have to wait 2 weeks for benefits due to a surgery?

Tags: canada, insurance, employment, benefits, unemployment

I have to go on Employment Insurance (EI) because I am having surgery and was wondering if I still have to wait the 2 week waiting period they make you wait until you can receive benefits or do they waive that 2 week waiting period because I'm having surgery as the reason for going on EI?

Comment: phone 1-800-206-7218--push 0--

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of your condition, you have to wait 2 weeks. I guess you might have found this out by now :)

Answer (score 1):

There are cirumstances in which the 2-week period can be waived, but not many - see here: http://www.servicecanada.gc.ca/eng/ei/types/special.shtml#waiting